# Upload video and create thumbnail from video in django

Tags: python, django, video

Is there any model field for video in django?
Any suggestion for plugin or snippets will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at the [django-video](http://code.google.com/p/django-video/) app. It supports [thumbnail generation](http://code.google.com/p/django-video/wiki/README).

Answer (score 13):

MoviePy doesn't handle uploading in Django, but it can do thumbnail generation very easily:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
clip = VideoFileClip("example.mp4")
clip.save_frame("thumbnail.jpg",t=1.00)
```

http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html

Comment: hello, thanks for this. But I have a problem. How can I get the image 'thumbnail.jpg' and save it to my ImageField. Because when I print clip=VideoFileClip(path).save_frame('thumb.jpg',t=0.00) it will return None.